# Можно ли в Python определить город по коду аэропорта

Tags: python, python-3.x

Можно ли в Python определить город по коду аэропорта, например ATL?

```
from pyairports.airports import Airports
airports = Airports()
airports.airport_iata(iata) # namedtuple(airport, [name, city, country, iata, icao, lat, lon, alt, tz, dst, tzdb]) or AirportNotFoundException
airports.other_iata(iata)   # namedtuple(other, [iata, name, country, subdiv, type, lat, lon]) or AirportNotFoundException
airports.lookup(iata)       # namedtuple(airport) or namedtuple(other) or AirportNotFoundException
```

Comment: А как бы вы это сделали в любом другом языке? А если вообще без языка?

Comment: Вообще без языка - Google, а с другими языками пока не знакома, к сожалению((

Comment: Я не знаю, как соотносится код аэропорта с городом. И предположу, что большинство программистов тоже не знает. Хорошо бы понять, как это без программирования делается

Comment: Если вы сможете найти какой-то алгоритм или справочник, пожалуйста, приведите его в вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit]. А то сейчас вопрос не о [tag:python] получается

Comment: Вы же сами привели пример использования модуля pyairports, который содержит в себе базу аэропортов. Тогда в чем проблема с использованием данного кода ?

Comment: Не работает этот модуль 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [80], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from pyairports.airports import Airports

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyairports'

Comment: а вы модуль установили ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модуль надо предварительно поставить:

```
pip install pyairports
```

Дальше используете практически как в вашем примере:

```
from pyairports.airports import Airports

iata = 'SVO'
airports = Airports()
airport = airports.airport_iata(iata)
print(airport.city)
```

Вывод:

```
Moscow
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, CrazyElf! pip install pyairports - не поставила изначально модуль. Всё работает)

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеке которую вы используете данные выдаются в виде:
`tuple(airport, [name, city, country, iata, icao, lat, lon, alt, tz, dst, tzdb])` 
а значит что к каждому `(airport)` , привязан его `[name, city, country]` , с данной библиотекой я не работал но тут кортеж в котором есть массив с нужными вам данными, просто достаньте их используя ключевые слова для поиска, что-то вроде:

```
 if (user == tuple): // аэропорты будут указаны в виде их кода.
    print(tuple[city]) // а города это данные в массиве, значит все корректно.
```

это грубый пример, просто чтобы была ясна общая картина.

для лучшего ознакомления с тем что вы используйте, советую покопаться тут: https://github.com/NICTA/pyairports

Comment: Благодарю, Mark! Именно на Github я и нашла этот модуль.